# Manga where the main character gets sent to Hell to become a god, to help angels fight demons

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Manga where the main character gets sent to Hell to become a god, to help angels fight demons. He finds a rock snake and names it Onix.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is ***[The Constellation That Returned From Hell](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=173152)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-celestial-returned-from-hell):

> Yeonseung Choi, the first human ever to become a celestial! He goes off to train in the Abyss to stop other celestials from swallowing Earth whole. Will he be able to protect Earth...?

From Baka-Updates:

> I’ve returned from hell. After enduring for thousands of years, I will be the one to save humanity.

The modern world has become connected to a realm called the Abyss, which is filled with monsters and godlike beings known as 'Constellations'. The Constellations are divided into two opposing races, one resembling angels, the other, demons.

On Earth, some humans have taken on the job of 'Hunter', in order to protect the world from dungeons and monsters. The protagonist of the story is Yeonseung Choi, a C+ rank Hunter whose chosen skill is martial arts.

Yeonseung is summoned by one of the angelic Constellations, referring to herself as the 'Goddess of Balance', who's foreseen that the demonic Constellations intend to send powerful monsters to invade the Earth, and that the only one who can stop them is Yeonseung.

In order to become strong enough to combat these monsters though, Yeonseung must first train by fighting monsters in the Abyss. Wishing to become stronger, and to save the world, Yeonseung agrees to these terms, and is sent to the Abyss.

Upon arriving in the Abyss, Yeonseung is swept up by a magic storm, which infuses his body with magic energy, increasing his bone strength and muscle density. A few weeks later, the storm deposits him back on the ground, where he spots a huge stone serpent, which reminds him of the Pokemon, [Onix](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Onix_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

Viewing this as an opportunity to train, Yeonseung starts laying into the serpent with punches, but it ignores him, his initial blows having no apparent effect. He keeps plugging away though, gradually accumulating more power with each blow landed, and eventually levels up enough to upgrade his class and knock the serpent down.

Seeing tears in the serpent's eyes afterwards, he chooses not to kill it, and it becomes a companion of sorts, which he addresses as 'Onix'.

[image] [image]